# jQuery animate scrollTop vs requestAnimationFrame - Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css, requestanimationframe

If I have a page with lots of images with lots of CSS effects and CSS animations applied to them, would I get a performance gain from using `window.scrollTo` in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop vs using jQuery's `$("html").animate({ scrollTop: "x" })` to programmatically scroll the page to a certain point "x"?

Tl;DR — rAF + `window.scrollto()` vs `.animate({scrollTop: "x"})` performance

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it? What did you see?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I'm very new to rAF and am wondering if the performance gain, if any, would be worth my time.

Comment: I'm also curious about this! I'm building a parallax site and the scrolling animations can be very choppy at times. Did you try this yet?

Answer (score 1):

`window.scrollTo()` is faster because it's native JavaScript.  Any calls to jQuery are slower because both `$()` and `.animate()` will each (probably) take more time than the single `window.scrollTo()` call.  It's also wasteful to use `.animate({scrollTop ...` without a time because you could just use `$("html").scrollTop()`.  Regardless, `window.scrollTo()` should be even faster than that and has the advantage of being cross-browser comaptible.  I would say use that if you're not going to animate the scrolling.

*Disclaimer:* you probably won't see much of a performance difference.

Comment: I think .animate() defaults to 400ms with no time specified. I'm sure the use of raw js would create a small performance boost. I was more so wondering if the use of rAF over .animate() will help avoid jank as detailed here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/rendering